# Find Variance of random variable $X=2Y-3Z$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance

Find Variance of random variable $X=2Y-3Z$. Given that $EY=0,EZ=2,VarX=2,VarZ=1,p(Y,Z)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},EX=6$.

Knowing that $Var(X)=Var(2Y)+Var(-3Z)+2(E(-6YZ)-E(2Y)E(-3Z)).$ Remains only to find $E(YZ)$. This is where I am stuck now. $E(YZ)=\sum_{(yz)} yzp(y,z)$ I am not sure what are values for $y,z$ in this case.

Comment: Is $p(Y,Z)$ the covariance $Cov(Y, Z)$ by any chance? Clearly it cannot be a PMF value, as it is negative...

Comment: @MTurgeon I am not sure also. Can it be correlation?

Comment: Yes, it could very well be correlation. It's typically represented by the Greek letter $\rho$ (pronounced "rho"), which does look like a $p$. Assuming it's the correlation, and given the variances, you can find the covariance $Cov(Y,Z)$. Can you write the variance of $X$ as a function of variances and covariances, instead of expected values? Or alternatively, can you relate $E(YZ)$ and $Cov(Y, Z)$?

Comment: @MTurgeon Yes it's already clear,thanks

Comment: Is this a trick question (with the answer just being hidden but directly given among the given data) or is there a typo in the condition "$VarX=2$"?  Also, it looks like the given data are inconsistent, since by linearity of expectation you should have $E(X) = 2E(Y) - 3E(Z) = -6 \ne 6$.